# Rollback/commit was called outside transaction

Tags: transactions

Can anyone explain what is meant by "Rollback was called outside transaction" or "Commit was called outside transaction". When can these statements be displayed?

Comment: You should add information about what DBMS is used. In general, you need to start transaction before you can commit it / roll it back.

Comment: SQL server is used. The scenario is when a file (usually an order file for shipping customer items/orders, eg:amazon e-shopping) has been downloaded to application, the mentioned error occurs while downloading those data from file.